# tomcat fail to update newly compiled java files

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am using tomcat 6 web server to do some jsp stuff.

If I made some changes to an associated **java** file and compile it, tomcat fail to reflect such changes.(if those changes are made to **jsp** file, it is ok)

However, if I restart the tomcat server, the changes are reflected and everything goes as I expect.

I doubt it is the server cache thing. How can I solve it?

Comment: How are you deploying your newly compiled class files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For convenience, you can use Tomcat's `Manager` to [*Reload An Existing Application*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Reload_An_Existing_Application).

Addendum: As @Paul comments, [*Executing Manager Commands With Ant*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant) provides a better long-term way to deal with this.

Comment: Tomcat ships with a jar of Ant tasks for managing the container and deploying apps.  I prefer to undeploy and deploy as part of my build process.  [This](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant) has information on how to set that up.